# When is a power real?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

We know that the power $a^b$ is, if $b$ is not an integer, the product of a power and a root (example : $2^{2.5}=2^2\sqrt{2}$).

But how do we know, if $a$ is negative, if $a^b$ is complex ?

For example, $(-1)^{2.5}$ is complex ($i$), but $(-1)^\frac{7}{3}$ is real. For simple exponents, it seems simple, but how to know when the exponent is more "complicated" ?

Comment: How do you define $(-1)^{2.5}$? I find $-i$, not $i$... How do you define $(-1)^{7/3}$? I find $\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$, not a real... And so on.

Comment: $(-1)^{2.5} = (-1)^2*(-1)^\frac{1}{2} = 1*i = i$

Comment: $(-1)^\frac{7}{3} = (-1)^2*(-1)^\frac{1}{3} = 1*-1$ Maybe incorrect, but that's what I thought

Comment: Use De Moivre's theorem for complicated exponents

Comment: Then why $(-1)^{1/2}=i$ instead of $-i$ and why $(-1)^{1/3}=-1$ and not the complex number I suggested? In case you are wondering, these are quite serious objections and the base line here is that one cannot manipulate powers of complex numbers as if they were powers on nonnegative real numbers (except if the powers are integer powers). So, for example, there is no way to assign a single value to $(-1)^{7/3}$...

Comment: Oh ok. What are the current way of calculations of fractional exponents ?

Comment: @Hugh Leading to multiple values.

Comment: "What are the current way of calculations of fractional exponents" If a polar form of $w\ne0$ is $w=re^{it}$, the solutions of $$z^q=w^p$$ for given integers $(p,q)$ are $$z=r^{p/q}\exp(i(t+2k\pi)p/q)$$ for integers $k$. One should refrain to translate this as $z=w^{p/q}$ since there is no canonical (and continuous) way to define a function $w\mapsto w^{p/q}$ on $\mathbb C$ except when $p/q$ is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Well $(-1)^{\frac73}=\sqrt[3]{(-1)^7}=\sqrt[3]{-1}$, which has $3$ solutions, **some real and some not**.

In order to solve $\sqrt[3]{-1}$, draw the unit circle, and then:

- Draw the 1st solution, which is obviously $-1$, or more generally: $\cos(\pi)+\sin(\pi)i$
- Rotate it $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ radians in order to get the 2nd solution: $\cos(\pi+\frac{2\pi}{3})+\sin(\pi+\frac{2\pi}{3})i$
- Rotate it $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ radians in order to get the 3rd solution: $\cos(\pi+\frac{4\pi}{3})+\sin(\pi+\frac{4\pi}{3})i$

As you can see:

- The 1st solution is real, because $\sin(\pi)=0$
- The 2nd solution is not real, because $\sin(\pi+\frac{2\pi}{3})\neq0$
- The 3rd solution is not real, because $\sin(\pi+\frac{4\pi}{3})\neq0$

Here is a graphic illustration:

[image]

Comment: I like pictures.  +1

Answer (score 0):

What about the following: a number is real if the imaginary component is zero.

Let's have a look at `a = abs(a) * (cos(180°) + i * sin(180°)) = abs(a) * (e^180°)`
`a^b = abs(a)^b * (e^(180°*b)) = abs(a) * (cos(180°*b) + i * sin(180°*b))`
This is real if the imaginary part is zero:
`sin(180°*b) = 0`
This is true if `180°*b` is a whole multiple of 180°, which means that `b` is a whole number.

This means that for a negative number `a`: `a^b` is real if `b` is a whole number.